# About toList() in Dart

Tags: dart

Why do I get nothing when I remove `toList()`?

```
void main() {
  var i = 0;

  final cc = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  cc.map((name) {
    print(name);
    i++;
    print(i);
  }).toList();
}
```

Comment: please format your code a bit more, it doesnt give people the will to help you if you don't make their task easy in the first place. Your question seems legit though.

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking on the check mark. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**map**](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) method in Dart returns a *lazy iterable*, which isn't evaluated until you actually iterate it. Calling `toList()`, in addition to returning an actual list, forces this evaluation.

This is why nothing is printed unless you use `toList()`.

Comment: Instead of using `cc.map((name) => ... ).toList()`, you can use `cc.forEach((name) => ...)` or, preferably `for (var name in cc) ...`.